# Unable to understand why my application is not showing map as I add all requirement.

Tags: android, android-layout

I was working on mapview but I am unable to get mapview but only gird lines.

I am following http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html but do not know what is missing.

I have generated My api keys.

Answer (score 0):

Did u generate api key correctly as per in this link. http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html and check whether you have given Internet permission in you manifest file. Since this permission allows you to download map to your application. Did you run in emulator or device?

Comment: Thanks for answer,i came to know where was the problem actually i was using release key not debug key;( and now unable to generate 5md certificate as i changed my debug.keystore in to txt file would you tell how i can change it again?